# A canonical map from a Euclidean cone-manifold $M^3$ to $\mathbb{E}^3/\mathrm{Hol}(M)$

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, euclidean-geometry, orbifolds

Suppose we have a 3-dimensional Euclidean cone-manifold $M$—in my book that just means $M$ is a manifold whose geometry is constructed by gluing it out of Euclidean tetrahedra, with faces paired by isometries. $M$ shares many common properties with an $(\mathbb{E}^3,\mathrm{E}(3))$-manifold: it has a universal cover $p:\tilde{M}\to M$, constructed by removing its singular locus $M_s$, taking the usual universal cover, and then re-inserting $M_s$; it has a developing map $\mathrm{dev}:\tilde{M}\to\mathbb{E}^3$, and therefore it has a holonomy map $\mathrm{hol}:\pi_1(M\setminus M_s)\to\mathrm{E}(3)$, unique up to conjugacy (in older literature this is sometimes called the *monodromy*). The image of the map $\mathrm{hol}$ I denote by $\mathrm{Hol}(M)$. The definition of holonomy is such that, for any $x\in M$, any two elements of $\mathrm{dev}(p^{-1}(x))$ are related by an element of $\mathrm{Hol}(M)$. Therefore the assignment $x\mapsto q(\mathrm{dev}(p^{-1}(x)))$ gives a well-defined map $q_M:M\to\mathbb{E}^3/\mathrm{Hol}(M)$, where $q:\mathbb{E}^3\to\mathbb{E}^3/\mathrm{Hol}(M)$ is the quotient map. This is the canonical map mentioned in the title.

Now for my question. In the event that $\mathbb{E}^3/\mathrm{Hol}(M)$ is a suitably *nice* space (for instance, a compact Euclidean orbifold), what is known about this map $q_M$? It seems to arise so naturally that I feel it must have been studied before, probably in a more general setting. It seems to me that it should be a ramified covering map (a surjection which is a covering map outside of the singular locus). Anything else?